# Kubernetes: How to get disk / cpu metrics of a node

Tags: kubernetes

Without using Heapster is there any way to collect like CPU or Disk metrics about a node within a Kubernetes cluster?

How does Heapster even collect those metrics in the first place?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Kubernetes monitoring is detailed in the documentation [here](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/monitoring.html), but that mostly covers tools using heapster.

Node-specific information is exposed through the cAdvisor UI which can be accessed on port 4194 (see the commands below to access this through the proxy API).

Heapster queries the kubelet for stats served at `<kubelet address>:10255/stats/` (other endpoints can be found in the code [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/pkg/kubelet/server.go#L971)).

Try this:

```
$ kubectl proxy &
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
$ NODE=$(kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ curl -X "POST" -d '{"containerName":"/","subcontainers":true,"num_stats":1}' localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/nodes/${NODE}:10255/stats/container
...
```

Note that these endpoints are not documented as they are intended for internal use (and debugging), and may change in the future (we eventually want to offer a more stable versioned endpoint).

**Update:**

As of Kubernetes version 1.2, the Kubelet exports a "summary" API that aggregates stats from all Pods:

```
$ kubectl proxy &
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
$ NODE=$(kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
$ curl localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/nodes/${NODE}:10255/stats/summary
...
```

Comment: Hey Tim, I'm unclear what your trying to do exactly (since in general I'm still new to Kubernetes)

Comment: Do you mean what the example commands I posted are doing? It sends a POST request to the `/stats/container` endpoint of a node, and prints the results (to STDOUT). The command `kubectl get nodes -o=jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}"` is just a fancy way of grabbing the name of a random node.

Comment: Is there a syntax error in the get nodes? It seems to be failing when I'm running it on my master server.

Comment: It works fine for me. What's the error you're getting? What's the output of `kubectl get nodes`?

Comment: It says the formatting is incorrect, something is wrong with the -o=jsonpath output

Comment: Hmm, might be a version issue. If you just type `kubectl get nodes` it should list the available nodes, and you can manually pick one to insert into the URL in the 3rd command.

Comment: I am trying to get the metrics of a single pod container. I can get the metrics, but couldn't find a way to calculate the usage percentage. Is there any document where I can find the formula to calculate the usage percentage?

Comment: I get "getsockopt: connection refused" for port 10255

Comment: recent version change to `curl localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/${NODE}/proxy/stats/summary`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using heapster to collect metrics. It's pretty straight forward. However, in order to access those metrics, you need to add "type: NodePort" in hepaster.yml file. I modified the original heapster files and you can found them [here](https://gitlab.com/abushoeb/kubernetes/tree/master/heapster). See my readme file how to access metrics. More metrics are available [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster/blob/master/docs/model.md).

Metrics can be accessed via a web browser by accessing http://heapster-pod-ip:heapster-service-port/api/v1/model/metrics/cpu/usage_rate. The Same result can be seen by executing following command.

```
$ curl -L http://heapster-pod-ip:heapster-service-port/api/v1/model/metrics/cpu/usage_rate
```