# Docker stats for docker containers in kubernetes returning empty values

Tags: docker, monitoring, kubernetes

I am trying to get the stats of the containers that are running inside the kubernetes nodes via **docker stats** command. But unfortunately I am getting all the values as "0" for all the pod containers.

```
CONTAINER     CPU %   MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %   NET I/O     BLOCK I/O   PIDS
7dc5af9923b2  0.00%         0 B / 0 B     0.00%   0 B / 0 B   0 B / 0 B    0
```

I did the same with containers that I brought up manually via **docker run** command in the same node and I am getting proper values for those containers.

```
CONTAINER     CPU %    MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %    NET I/O       BLOCK I/O       PIDS
8be93c039a25  0.12%   133.3 MB / 3.892 GB    3.43%   0 B / 648 B  2.208 MB / 0 B     0
```

Is there any specific method to get the stats fot the pod containers other than this?

Note: docker version is 1.11.2 and kube version is 1.3.7

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35212987/759019 ?

Comment: Yeah, I referred that and thanks for the suggestion. I can get the metrics of the entire node and also sub containers list. But I can't find an API to get the metric for each container. Is there any document for the related APIs? It will be much helpful for me.

Comment: I got it. I referred the document that was mentioned in that post. Now i could get the metrics of the container as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this one. I used the kubelet API to get the metrics for the node and well as for individual containers. The following API will return the metrics for a pod container.

```
http://<nodeIP>:10255/stats/<podName>/<containerName> - POST
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212008/kubernetes-how-to-get-disk-cpu-metrics-of-a-node/35212987#35212987)  that was suggested in the comments was much helpful.

[This](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/pkg/kubelet/server.go#L971) document has some more APIs to collect the metrics.

Comment: I got the values, but still can't able to calculate the usage percentage. I couldn't find any documentation related to the calculation part. It would be great if some one helps me. I need to calculate the CPU percentage and memory usage of each container.